# IE can't access to Wepshere Admin Console or Servlets, but Chrome can

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, console, websphere, admin

I got a weird situation this week where I lost my access to WAS admin console/Servlets using inner browser or internet explorer suddenly.
I'm sure, WAS is running and my applications is started because i can access the server via Chrome.

To sum up,
 IE doesn't open:
localhost:9082/SomeInputServlet or http:///SomeInputServlet.
The same case is true for admin console and inner browser.

Chrome can open only:  http:///SomeInputServlet, not with he localhost.
Additionally, Chrome connects with https, not http.(Security is enabled on the server)

And also, server can be reached from other computers in the newtork with Chrome too.

Everything was ok before and i don't what can cause such a situation.
I reset my all ie settings, but it didn't work.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. 
When I remove ie 8, and install ie 9, problem is solved. 
I don't why but, it seems things are messed up in ie 8.